# Удаление строки dataGridView и mysql

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

Удаление строки из грида работает,но почему то не удаляется из базы данных.Таблица bd.sqlite таблица tovari.

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        int ind = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(ind);
        m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
        m_dbConn.Open();
        m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;
        string del = "DELETE FROM tovari WHERE id";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(del, m_dbConn);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по участку кода, не хватает вызова command.ExecuteNonQuery().
И еще лучше SQLiteConnection обернуть в using, что бы не забыть закрыть соединение.

Comment: Крашится,при добавлении command.ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: @goga А с какой ошибкой ?

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c639421/v639421667/661af/2bbUEA7nkyk.jpg

Comment: @goga 1. Вы не у того объекта вызываете метод ExecuteNonQuery. (у вас команда - это переменная command). 2. Вы не правильно в текст запроса передаете значение переменной ind, надо так "DELETE FROM tovari WHERE id = " + ind. И еще, Вы уверены что номер строки в гриде совпадает с id в таблице БД?

Comment: поправил,ошибок нет,но в базе так же,ничего не меняется.

Comment: @goga Я писал выше "Вы уверены что номер строки в гриде совпадает с id в таблице БД" ? Если в грид вы передаете id, то лучше вытаскивать его и передавать в запрос.

Comment: Да,совпадают,и там и там.А по поводу заноса,делаю так:
string query = "SELECT * FROM tovari";
После массив,и вывод в грид.

Comment: @goga Тогда в конце еще вызовите коммит m_dbConn.Commit(); Так же можно посмотреть что возвращает метод ExecuteNonQuery() (он возвращает количество строк, на которые повлиял запрос, в данном случае количество удаленных строк)